# Creating an additional AWS policy within a lambda child module gives invalid index

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies

Forgive me if this question is a little basic, I'm quite new to both AWS and Terraform.

I'm trying to create a lambda function via a terraform module. The source of the module is pointing at this repo https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/tree/master.

I am trying to follow the complete example [provided](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/examples/complete/main.tf#L130) starting at 130 of terraform-aws-lambda/examples/complete/main.tf but in my case I need to set 2 policies rather than 1.

I have:

```
   number_of_policy_jsons = 2

   policy_jsons = [
    <<-EOT
      {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
              {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                      "xray:*"
                  ],
                  "Resource": ["*"]
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
              {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                      "s3:*"
                  ],
                  "Resource": ["*"]
              }
          ]
      }
    EOT
  ]
```

I'm guessing I've formatted the json incorrectly but I can not figure out how it is supposed to be done. No matter what I try I get this error.

```
     Error: Invalid index
    │ 
    │  126:   policy = var.policy_jsons[count.index] 
    │     ├────────────────
    │     │ count.index is 1
    │     │ var.policy_jsons is list of string with 1 element
    │ 
    │ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the given index is greater than or
    │ equal to the length of the collection.
```

If someone could explain how this is supposed to be used that would be so helpful.

Comment: Can you add the entire module call to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you should format your list like this :

```
policy_jsons = [<<EOF
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "xray:*"
              ],
              "Resource": ["*"]
          }
      ]
  }
EOF,
<<EOF
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "s3:*"
              ],
              "Resource": ["*"]
          }
      ]
  }
EOF

]
```

It's not very pretty to look at, another solution is to us [Data Source: aws_iam_policy_document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document)

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "xray" {
    statement {
        actions = ["xray:*"]
        resources = ["*"]
    }
}
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3" {
    statement {
        actions = ["s3:*"]
        resources = ["*"]
    }
}
```

and then

```
policy_jsons = [
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.xray.json,
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3.json
]
```